# Conductor build error Execution failed for task ':conductor-annotations:spotlessJavaCheck'

Tags: spring, gradle, netflix, conductor

i try to build conductor from netflix to use it in my micro services application, but when i do it, i get an error while building conductor, i don't know what im doing wrong, i use docker-compose build, how it is described in documentation but it not works. Here is error output, it have some more details, but i can not copy it all here because of limit on the page, in the rest of the output is same problem with format violations:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':conductor-annotations:spotlessJavaCheck'.
> The following files had format violations:
      src/main/java/com/netflix/conductor/annotations/protogen/ProtoEnum.java
          @@ -1,26 +1,26 @@
          -/*\r\n
          - * Copyright 2022 Netflix, Inc.\r\n
          - * <p>\r\n
          - * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with\r\n
          - * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at\r\n
          - * <p>\r\n
          - * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\r\n
          - * <p>\r\n
          - * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on\r\n
          - * an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the\r\n
          - * specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\r\n
          - */\r\n
          -package com.netflix.conductor.annotations.protogen;\r\n
          -\r\n
          -import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;\r\n
          -import java.lang.annotation.Retention;\r\n
          -import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;\r\n
          -import java.lang.annotation.Target;\r\n
          -\r\n
          -/**\r\n
          - * ProtoEnum annotates an enum type that will be exposed via the GRPC API as a native Protocol\r\n
          - * Buffers enum.\r\n
          - */\r\n
          -@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)\r\n
          -@Target(ElementType.TYPE)\r\n
          -public @interface ProtoEnum {}\r\n
          +/*\n
          + * Copyright 2022 Netflix, Inc.\n
          + * <p>\n
          + * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with\n
          + * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at\n
          + * <p>\n
          + * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\n
          + * <p>\n
          + * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on\n
          + * an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the\n
          + * specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\n
          + */\n
          +package com.netflix.conductor.annotations.protogen;\n
          +\n
          +import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;\n
          +import java.lang.annotation.Retention;\n
          +import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;\n
          +import java.lang.annotation.Target;\n
          +\n
          +/**\n
          + * ProtoEnum annotates an enum type that will be exposed via the GRPC API as a native Protocol\n
          + * Buffers enum.\n
      ... (4 more lines that didn't fit)
  Violations also present in:
      src/main/java/com/netflix/conductor/annotations/protogen/ProtoField.java
      src/main/java/com/netflix/conductor/annotations/protogen/ProtoMessage.java
  Run './gradlew :conductor-annotations:spotlessApply' to fix these violations.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':conductor-annotations:spotlessJavaCheck'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:420)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:342)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor.process(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:96)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.executeWithServices(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:140)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:125)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:54)
        at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.execute(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$executeTasks$7(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:161)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$tryTransition$7(StateTransitionController.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.tryTransition(StateTransitionController.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.executeTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:161)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.runWork(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:156)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.doRun(DefaultBuildController.java:164)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.access$000(DefaultBuildController.java:45)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController$BuildOpRunnable.run(DefaultBuildController.java:183)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
```

Comment: Ran into the same problem today. Did you find solution for this Karol Wolny?

Comment: No, if u find, write it here